# Spring jsp с jstl отображается как текст

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

```
@RestController
public class GeneralPageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/general", method = GET)
    private ModelAndView doGet(Model model) {
        return new ModelAndView("General");
    }

}
```

//

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value = "com.marketplace")
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }


}
```

//

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HikariCP connection pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

В  браузере
[image: в браузере]

Причем если я удаляю

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fmt" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

то jsp открывается но не работает jstl

Answer (score 0):

Я так и не смог найти для себя рабочего решения с maven. В итоге пересобрал проект под gradle и проблема решилась.

мой build.gradle, если вдруг кто-то столкнется с такой же проблемой

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven {

        url "https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content"

        credentials {
            username = '<Oracle Account email address>'
            password = '<Oracle Account password>'
        }
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile group: 'cn.easyproject', name: 'ojdbc7', version: '12.1.0.2.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.193'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl
    compile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path
    compile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.2.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP
    compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '2.6.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '9.0.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
}
```